# How can I return a Json in controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this function in my controller:

```
gerencia.pay_charge(params: params, body: payment)
```

This function returns:

```
{"code"=>200, "data"=>{"barcode"=>"03399.75039 21000.000006 74992.301015 6 69020000002250", "link"=>"https://exmaple.com.br/emissao/110276_19_NAEMAL1/A4XB-110276-74992-XILE0", "expire_at"=>"2016-08-30", "charge_id"=>97611, "status"=>"waiting", "total"=>2250, "payment"=>"banking_billet"}}
```

How can I send it in json format?

I have the example in php but I don't know how do it in rails.

In php is this:

```
$payment = $apiGN->payCharge($params, $paymentBody);
echo json_encode($payment);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
render json: gerencia.pay_charge(params: params, body: payment)
```

The above line of code sets a Content-Type of `application/json` and  automatically converts the object(ruby hash) to JSON.

For more, look for `rendering json` in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Comment: `to_json` is excess here.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.